# How to fix all test cases for classifyStrings code on codesignal python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, testcase

So I am given this question: You categorize strings into three types: good, bad, or mixed. If a string has 3 consecutive vowels or 5 consecutive consonants, or both, then it is categorized as bad. Otherwise it is categorized as good. Vowels in the English alphabet are ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"] and all other letters are consonants.

The string can also contain the character ?, which can be replaced by either a vowel or a consonant. This means that the string "?aa" can be bad if ? is a vowel or good if it is a consonant. This kind of string is categorized as mixed.

This is the code I created so far:

```
def classifyStrings(s):
    l = list(s)
    numberofvowels = 0
    numberofconsonants = 0
    punctuationpresent = False
    for i in l:
        if i == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":
            numberofvowels += 1
        else:
            numberofconsonants += 1
    if numberofvowels >= 3 or numberofconsonants >=5 and i != '?':
        return "bad"
    else:
        return "good"
        if i in l == "?":
            punctuationpresent = True
            return "mixed"
```

So far I have managed to pass 5/17 test cases. I'm not sure how to improve this code to pass all test cases. The main issues that I have to fix are: question mark between vowels or between consonants e.g. a?a,consonants in between vowels e.g. aba, vowels in between consonants e.g. bab

Comment: `if i == "a" or "e" or "i" or "o" or "u":` is not the correct way to compare multiple values. Use `if i == "a" or i == "e" or i == "i" or i == "o" or i == "u":`. Or the more concise: `if i in "aeiou":`

Comment: Also, the `return "good"` makes all the code below it unreachable.

Comment: The mixed string is unclear. Does any string with a "?" in it get marked as mixed? Or are you supposed to replace the "?" with a vowel or consonant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:  After thinking about this over night I defined a few more test cases and as a resuilt was required to further change the solution. as shown below:
Here is an approach that seems to address all cases properly:

```
def classifyStrings(s):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    max_vowels = 3
    max_consonants = 5
    vowel_count = 0
    consonant_count = 0
    punctuation_present = False
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == '?':
        punctuation_present = True
    elif s[i].lower() in vowels:
        if punctuation_present and i> 0 and vowel_count == 0 and s[i-1] != '?':
            punctuation_present = False
        vowel_count += 1
        consonant_count = 0        
    else:
        if punctuation_present and i> 0 and consonant_count == 0 and s[i-1] != '?':
            punctuation_present = False
        consonant_count += 1
        vowel_count = 0
    if vowel_count == max_vowels  or consonant_count == max_consonants:
        return 'bad'
    else:
        if punctuation_present and (vowel_count == max_vowels -1 or consonant_count == max_consonants-1):
            return 'mixed'

return 'good'
```

Given a series of tests cases:

```
test_cases = {"good": ['aabbccee', 'bbbbaaddd', 'eeffffeffffiig', 'a?bbdu', 'a?deffff', 'f?ekkii'],
             'bad':['ooobbbddbee','eeebb', 'eedgfkjii', 'kelyzzccbb', 'a?deffffg','f?ekkiii'],
             'mixed':['iipp?hhoo', 'hjkie?drte', 'o?aekee']}
```

running:

```
for k, sl in test_cases.items():
    print(f'Testing {k} cases')
    for s in sl:
        print(f'\tResults: {classifyStrings(s)}')
```

Yields:

```
Testing good cases
    Results: good
    Results: good
    Results: good
    Results: good
    Results: good
    Results: good
Testing bad cases
    Results: bad
    Results: bad
    Results: bad
    Results: bad
    Results: bad
    Results: bad
Testing mixed cases
    Results: mixed
    Results: mixed
    Results: mixed
```

Comment: I purposely indented it like that. Thank you so much for the help but when I ran it using your code it switched to 2/17 test cases passed haha. But I really appreciate it regardless!

Comment: @Iman.G I have provided an updated solution, which addresses all the test cases I can think of, if you have additional test cases that don't pass let me know.

Comment: Hiya, thank you so much for helping me! I tried your previous version and it increased to 10/17 cases and I forgot to thank you! When I tried your updated version it kept giving me "s" is not defined in the for loop. I really appreciate everything you've done so far!

Comment: As defined in the function s is the name of the variable used by the function.  If your getting an error you didn't copy the function correctly or you are calling it incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def classifyStrings(s):
    if re.findall('(([aeiou]{3})|[^aeiou?]{5})',s):
        return 'bad'
    if '?' in s:
        a = classifyStrings(s.replace('?','a',1))
        b = classifyStrings(s.replace('?','n',1))
        return a if a == b else 'mixed'
    return 'good'
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it